# how to extend Ext.grid.header.container class

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have 10 grids in my project where I want to define one extra header, and that header will open menu on double click, single click will return null. This functionality works fine in my 3.4 version. But somehow i am not able to extend 'Ext.grid.header.container' class. Any suggestion why?? Please refer below my code.

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.HeaderColumnModel', {

    extend: 'Ext.grid.header.container',

    initComponent: function()
    {
         this.callParent();
    }
}


Usage

columns : new Ext.grid.HeaderColumnModel()
OR
colModel:  new Ext.grid.HeaderColumnModel()
```

Comment: new Ext.grid ... better use Ext.create('Ext.grid.HeaderColumnModel', {}) method or xtype/widget

Comment: Thanks for giving better option. I changed that in my whole project. But even Ext.create('Ext.grid.HeaderColumnModel') does not bring view. And trouble is, it is not giving any error. Just does not load grid.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because case matters when extending a class. It should read `Ext.grid.header.Container` (notice the 'C' in "Container").